# (C#)MVC5 EF6 Ordering a collection and ordering sub collection in each item

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to order a collection of News Entities and each item has a subcollection of NewsComment I'd like to order. I've tried a few things, this is what I have right now, what am I doing wrong?

I tried to order the list with foreach linq,with no luck.

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var news = db.News.ToList();
            // Order NewsComments?, date stored as datetime2 for NewComment object
            news.ForEach(x => x.NewsComments.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date).ThenBy(d => DateTime.Now));
            HomeView homeView = new HomeView()
            {
                News = news.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Date)).ThenBy(x => DateTime.Now.ToString()).ToList(), // Pulling news and ordering by date(stored as string)
                GameServerNodes = db.GameServerNodes.Where(x => x.Visible == 1).ToList(),
                GameServerTypes = db.GameServerTypes.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList(),
                GameServersCount = db.GameServers.Count()
            };
            ViewBag.IsAdmin = steamAuthentication.IsAdmin(HttpContext);
            return View(homeView);
        }
```

This doesn't seem to change the ordering of the NewsComments at all. The News items are ordering properly.

Comment: var sortedList = news.ForEach(x => x.NewsComments.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date).ThenBy(d => DateTime.Now));

Comment: ForEach return is void in my enviroment with latest EntityFramework. So this code gives me error CS0815 "Cannot assign void to implicity type variable.". Still no luck with this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not edit your question to include the resolution rather leave a post under it and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have my assignment in the lamda expression. Here's what I ended up using

`news.ForEach(x => x.NewsComments = x.NewsComments.OrderBy(z => z.Date).ThenBy(d => DateTime.Now).ToList());`